# get the latest record from the table for each user

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table user_status, which stores the status for each user, everytime a status changes, i apppend the status in the user_status table.

```
id   status     created 
1    ACTIVE     08-10-2017 08:21:22
1    ACTIVE     08-10-2017 08:21:25
1    NON_ACTIVE 08-10-2017 08:22:23
2    NON_ACTIVE 08-10-2017 08:22:23
2    ACTIVE     08-11-2017 08:25:23
3    NON_ACTIVE 08-12-2017 08:23:23
```

What I am looking for is the last status for each user based on the created date
so the output I am looking is

```
id   status     created 
1    NON_ACTIVE 08-10-2017 08:22:23
2    ACTIVE     08-11-2017 08:25:23
3    NON_ACTIVE 08-12-2017 08:23:23
```

also once I do that, I am also interested to know if there is a way to get the second to last status (one before the last) status for each user

so output from this query i am looking ofr is

```
1    ACTIVE     08-10-2017 08:21:25
2    NON_ACTIVE 08-10-2017 08:22:23
3    NON_ACTIVE 08-12-2017 08:23:23
```

any suggestions, I

Answer (score 0):

Window functions to the rescue!

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by created desc) as seqnum,
             nth_value(status, 2) over (partition by id order by created desc) as second_status
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you don't want all the columns, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.id, max(t.created) as created,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) as last_status,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then status end) as second_status,
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by created desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: Any reason for an anonymous downvote on what looks like a correct answer?

Comment: i am not sure who did the downvote, I am still figuring out your query. i am not sure who did the downvote

Comment: @user641887 . . . It looks like a malicious downvoter, who simply downvoted the question and all answers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff gave you an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, i would suggest to get the details in one go rather than getting the first status and then going for the second one. Hope this below snippet helps.

```
SELECT B.ID,
  B.STATUS,
  B.CREATED
FROM
  (SELECT A.ID,
    A.STATUS,
    CREATED,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.CREATED DESC) RN
  FROM
    (SELECT 1 ID,'ACTIVE' STATUS,'08-10-2017 08:21:22' CREATED FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 ID,'ACTIVE' STATUS,'08-10-2017 08:21:25' CREATED FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 ID,'NON_ACTIVE' STATUS,'08-10-2017 08:22:23' CREATED FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 ID,'NON_ACTIVE' STATUS,'08-10-2017 08:22:23' CREATED FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 ID,'ACTIVE' STATUS,'08-11-2017 08:25:23' CREATED FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 ID,'NON_ACTIVE' STATUS,'08-12-2017 08:23:23' CREATED FROM DUAL
    )A
  )B
WHERE B.RN IN (1,2);
/
```